Mute a specific conversation on an Apple Watch of a Family member without their own iPhone
I want to mute a specific conversation on an Apple Watch of a Family member who does not have their own iPhone. (My AppleID and iPhone was used to set up their watch with their associated AppleId).
Related:

how to customize watch to silence certain texts - Apple Community - This requires the family member to have their own iPhone, which is not my case.
How do I silence Messages from a single person on my Apple Watch? - It is not clear how to actually do this. Also, it probably will not help, since it looks like it is a connection with iPhone. In my particular situation we do not have 1:1 connection.

How can they mute a messages thread on their watch?

You can mute a thread on Apple watch by swiping on the conversation list (from right to left).

You will see a delete option (red trash can) and a mute option (purple bell icon). Choose carefully the left side with the bell icon.

This is a great and simple method, hidden in plain sight! In addition to Apple Watch messages, it also works for iPhone messages.
